# How to navigate through next and previous message button on media player theme?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, navigation

**EDIT:** I have edited the code in the following question. What I am doing is, fetching all messages from database at once in array and then displayed all messages in marquee tag With the following code:

```
$player_msg = array();
$qgetplayermsg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player_message WHERE is_active = 1 ORDER BY msg_id DESC");
while($playermsg = mysql_fetch_array($qgetplayermsg)){
    array_push($player_msg, $playermsg['message']);
}
```

Then in player:

```
<!--FLASH PLAYER START //////////////////-->
        <div class="message_flashing">
            <div class="message_navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li id="stop"><a href="#" title="Stop" onClick="document.getElementById('mq_msg').setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"><img src="images/player/stop.png" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Previous Message" class="previousMessage" rel="0"><img src="images/player/backward.png" /></a></li>
                    <li id="pause"><a href="#" title="Pause" onClick="document.getElementById('mq_msg').setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"><img src="images/player/pause.png" /></a></li>
                    <li id="play"><a href="#" title="Pause" onClick="document.getElementById('mq_msg').setAttribute('scrollamount', 1, 0);"><img src="images/player/play.png" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Next Message" class="nextMessage" rel="0"><img src="images/player/forward.png" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="flash_text">
            
            <? for($p=0; $p<(count($player_msg)); $p++){?>
                <marquee scrollamount="1" id="mq_msg" class="pl_msg_id_<?=$p;?>">&diams;<?=$player_msg[$p];?></marquee>
            <? } ?>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--FLASH PLAYER ENDS //////////////////-->
```

I am using following jQuery code to manipulate the messages through player buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("sdsdsdsd");
    <? for($a=0; $a<(count($player_msg)); $a++){?>
    
        $(".pl_msg_id_<?=$a;?>").hide();
        
    <? } ?>
        
        $(".pl_msg_id_0").show();
      
      
        $('.nextMessage').click(function () {
            
            var pl_msg_id = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'),10);
            
            if(pl_msg_id < <?=count($player_msg)-1;?>){
    
                $(".pl_msg_id_"+pl_msg_id).hide();
                
                pl_msg_id = ++pl_msg_id;
                alert("pl_msg_id_"+pl_msg_id);

                $(".nextMessage").attr("rel", pl_msg_id);
                $(".previousMessage").attr("rel", pl_msg_id);
                
                $(".pl_msg_id_"+pl_msg_id).show();
                
            } else if(pl_msg_id > <?=count($player_msg)-1;?>){
                
                $("#mq_msg").attr('class', "pl_msg_id_"+<?=count($player_msg)?>);
                $("#mq_msg").html("No more messages!");
                
                }//end of if
            
        });
        
        $('.previousMessage').click(function () {
            
            var pl_msg_id = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'),10);
            
            if(pl_msg_id != -1){
    
                $(".pl_msg_id_"+pl_msg_id).hide();
                
                pl_msg_id = --pl_msg_id;
                alert(pl_msg_id);
                
                $(".nextMessage").attr("rel", pl_msg_id);
                $(".previousMessage").attr("rel", pl_msg_id);
                
                $(".pl_msg_id_"+pl_msg_id).show();
                
            } else if(pl_msg_id == -1) {
                
                $("#mq_msg").attr('class', "pl_msg_id");
                $("#mq_msg").html("No more messages!");
                
                }//end of if//end of if
        });
});
        
</script>
```

Now the problem I am facing is, When showing another marquee and hiding previous one, the text doesn't float or move or walk. Secondly, ELSE IF block not working in nextMessage and previousMessage click functions. Please Guide.

Comment: Not sure, with "media player buttons", are you referring to the buttons on the keyboard labelled "play", "rewind", "stop" and so on? If so: that cannot be done in a reliable way in a web application because those keys are differently mapped on each keyboard and each operating system. You can mark `keyboard shortcuts` for input elements on html markup level and evaluate the resulting events in js, but as said: that is not reliable with such _special_ keys.

Comment: Not really an answer to what I wrote about: so I guess you are _not_ referring to the keyboard buttons?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am not referring to the keyboard buttons.

Comment: About dynamic messages: well where do you get the messages from? The sql fetches several messages into an array, but the html code only embeds a single one (the first). So the messages are not present in the html. You want to fetch the next message using `AJAX` (dynamically) or by doing a full page reload upon evey click or do you want to embed _all_ messages on the first page load?

Comment: Exactly. I have fetched all messages from array and stored into an array. Initially , array of 0 content will be displayed in player. Rest of the array elements should be navigated through player buttons. For example, when user clicks on Next Message button, array element of 1 should be displayed, if clicked again, element 2 should be displayed. Similarly, when clicked on Previous Message button, element 1 should be displayed because the currently displayed element was 2 and so on.

Comment: Adding to @arkascha's comment. Best solution would be to render all messages on load itself and hide all elements except the first message. And on click show the respective message(hide/show).

Comment: @arkascha, anpsmn I have edited the question with some changes using jQuery approach. Please help. I am facing the errors mentioned above.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @tereško thanks, I will learn it later. First help me solve this issue, please.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the discussion in the comments deliverd additional information that should have been present in the question. With that additional information an answer is possible:

You have to make sure that the messages are present in the html markup, otherwise you cannot directly show them by means of js. Keep in mind that the php is executed only once after the request. If you embed only the first message into the html markup then the rest is *lost*. So either you have to fetch them later or you have to embed *all* messages in the html markup. Embedding all messages is easier, but you cannot access newer messages that were written after the page load.

Change the bottom of the html script like this to embed *all* messages, not just the first one:

```
<div class="flash_text">
    <input type="hidden" id="mg_msg_key" value="0">
    <?php 
        foreach ($player_msg as $key=>$val)
            sprintf('<marquee scrollamount="1" id="mq_msg_%s" class="%s">&diams;%s</marquee>'."\n", 
                    $key, (0==$key)?'':'mg_msg_hidden', htmlspecialchars($val) );
    ?>
</div>
```

Note that there is an additional hidden input field holding the key of the currently visible message. Also all messages except the first one have an additional css class `mg_msg_hidden`. You can now use that class on css level to hide all messages except the first by adding to your css rule set:

```
.mg_msg_hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

That done only the first message will be visible, the rest is present (check in the html markup!) but invisible. This is the starting point where you can now use js to control the visibility of single messages. Change your js to something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showMessage(key){
        $('html div.flash_text marquee').addClass('mg_msg_hidden');
        $('html div.flash_text marquee#mq_msg_'+key).removeClass('mg_msg_hidden');
    }
    function nextMessage(){
        var key='html div.flash_text input#mg_msg_key';
        $(key).val($(key).val()+1);
        showMessage($(key).val());
    }
    function previousMessage(){
        var key='html div.flash_text input#mg_msg_key';
        $(key).val($(key).val()-1);
        showMessage($(key).val());
    }
</script>
```

This is obviously just a starting point for you. I have not tested these lines but written them by scratch. They probably contain syntax errors and the like. You will have to adapt and extend the approach as you require.

Also I used the [JQuery](http://jquery.com) notation to access elements in a more convenient way. You should consider using such a js library in your project: it saves you quite a lot of hassle when your scripts get a little more complex.

Comment: This is not working, I have used the same code. I also tried to implement jQuery approach with the code, above mentioned in EDIT question. But facing some problems. I would appreciate if you help.

Comment: Hm, "does not work" is not really very helpful... what does that mean, ehat happens, what not? What error messages do you get in the console? One thing that strikes me as soon as a look over the edited question: You contruction in the "flash player" part `class="pl_msg_id_<?=$p;?>"` cannot work, it is invalid, you probably mean something like this `class="pl_msg_id_<?echo sprintf('',$p;?>"` The same a second time furter back in the same line. You should control if such lines work by looking at the generated html markup ("View page source" in the browser).

Comment: Also, you write that you are using the jQuery library now. You do take care that this library is loaded at the top of your page? You have to, you cannot use it without loading it. Either way: look for the error messages you get in the debug console of your browser. No way to debug your site with out that.

Comment: sprintf() does not work. The code you mentioned invalid, is working fine.

Comment: Well indeed, obviously it must be `class="pl_msg_id_<?php echo $p;?>"` or `class="<?php echo sprintf('pl_msg_id_%s',$p);?>"`. I was too fast, but frankly I would expect you to be able to spot what I mean with a hint like that. And sorry, I don't see any way how your construction `class="pl_msg_id_<?=$p;?>"` can produce any meaningful output. Anyways, when you claim that strange code is what you want, then where is your problem? Did you do anything I suggested? What is it you found in the generated html markup? Did you take a look into the debug console of your browser? What did you find there?